# Xamarin forms Maps from intent

Tags: xamarin.forms

How to receive **Location** from native Maps app into my Xamarin forms application. and when my application is opened it should open **Xamarin.Forms.Maps** on the specific location.
Suppose the user of my app received the location from client on whats app. He/She will open the location in Native app and from there when he chooses **share**, my app should appear in the list. When he/She chooses my app the the map should open and add a pin on that specific location.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean receiving data from other apps to your app, you can use **Share Extension** to achieve that.

iOS: [**Understand Share Extensions**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Share.html)

Android: **[Receiving simple data from other apps](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive)**

**Generally**, when sharing data between map apps, we will open a map app manually.

According to the current technical solution, there are two main ways to open another application.

- **One** is to integrate the SDK that needs to open the application.
- **Another** is using the URL Scheme.

**Both** of them can not be detected automatically and then open the another appilcation. Every third party Map apps all **expose** their url scheme or SDK to developers. It seems like our app can detect the other map apps automaticall. **Actually** the developers has defined the supported other map apps. **However**, we can detect the defined map apps whether installed in device. If installed, the shared menu will show it, else not.

About URL Scheme, iOS and Android has their ways to achieve that.More info can refer to each of their official document.

iOS: **[Defining a Custom URL Scheme for Your App](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content/defining_a_custom_url_scheme_for_your_app)**

Android: **[Interacting with Other Apps](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents)**